# image src is not displaying the page in php

Tags: image, src, display

**I'm trying to upload the img path in database and show them in the slider, but the problem is the img src is not showing the page assigned. Can any body tell me why the image src is not loading the page.

my code is below
 **slider.php slider has this image code**

:`<img src='<?php echo "imagetest.php?id=$id" ?> width="200">` the image path couldn't display the page

imagetest.php has following code:

this page is not showing up in img src of the slider

if (empty($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
        echo 'A valid image file id is required to display the image file.';
        exit;
    }

```
$imageId = $_GET['id'];

//connect to mysql database
if ($conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test')) {
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $content);
    $sql = "SELECT type, content FROM images where id = {$imageId}";

    if ($rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $imageData = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        mysqli_free_result($rs);
    } else {
        echo "Error: Could not get data from mysql database. Please try again.";
    }
    //close mysqli connection
    mysqli_close($conn);

} else {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to mysql database. Please try again.";
}   

if (!empty($imageData)) {
    // show the image.
    header("Content-type: {$imageData['type']}");
    echo $imageData['content'];
}
```

?>

Comment: Try '$sql = "SELECT type, content FROM images where id = ${imageId}";' and 'header("Content-type: " . ${imageData['type']} . ")";'

Comment: i tried as you said but still the first page is not loading the second one. Although the second page is working fine, its not showing up in the img src

Comment: Have you tried to open the image directly in the browser (ie: http://yoursite.com/imagetest.php?id=1)?

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents

```
<img src="<?php echo file_get_contents('imagetest.php?id='. $id);?>" width="200"/>
```

and remove header(), u don't need it.

Comment: hi Zejur, your code returned all the codes of that page. all i wanted was the image path

Comment: Open imagetest.php?id=1 in your browser and see if any error. If everything ok it should return image path only.

Comment: when I open imagetest.php?id=2, it returned--> uploads/banner1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In php file

```
function track(){
        header('Content-Type: image/gif');
        $image = 'image.gif';
        echo file_get_contents($image); 
}
```

In view file

```
<img src="track.php" width="200"/>
```

Hope it's help ^^